# Number of parameters that can be passed to an UDF in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Is there a limit on the number of parameters that can be passed to an UDF in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a hard limit of 22 arguments. You can check [`UDFRegistration`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2.0.0-preview/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/UDFRegistration.scala) to see how different variants of `register` method are generated as well as as [`ScalaUDF`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ScalaUDF.scala).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you mean the number of parameters only three, if you check [UserDefinedFunction](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.UserDefinedFunction)'s documentation, you will notice that those arguments are:

> f: AnyRef, dataType: DataType, inputTypes: Seq[DataType] =
>   immutable.this.Nil

On the other hand if you are referring to the number of parameters that can be passed to the anonymous function, which is the first parameter you can check it at [UDFRegistration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration).